# Do the resources from all breakpoints load at once or only when in use

Tags: css, responsive-design, breakpoints

Working on some load time issues with a responsive design and I cant find a clear answer anywhere on this.

If you are using separate resources for different break points, say a different image file at one break point than another, do both images load regardless of the break point you are viewing from or just the one being used at that break point. We are using css media queries to change the image

It was suggested we load smaller images for smaller break points to speed up load time but if both the original and the small version load, that obviously would hurt not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `<img>` elements, all of them will load when the page loads.

If you set different images using CSS rules (background url), only the currently applied image will load.

If you want to improve page load times, use image sprites. Make them cacheable, and users will have to load them only once. The savings from eliminated round trip calls to the server in most cases outweigh the extra loading time for a sprite by a wide margin.

Comment: I actually figured this out as you answered. I looked at the Dev tools resource panel and saw it was adding and removing the resources on resize. THANKS!